# Error in drupal "Notice: Undefined index: extension in require()..."

Tags: debugging

I am seeing this error on my page

> Notice: Undefined index: extension in require() (line 207 of
>   /home/....../public_html/includes/filetransfer/sftp.inc).

I have no idea from where. I tried doing search but I did not see any help.
Could you please guide why this message is poping up on all the pages.

Comment: I have not done any changes since yesterday , it was working fine, today morning I opened I see this error

Comment: Looks like someone else was hacking your site, if that's the case. We can't know who, or what he did, or how to reverse it.

Comment: That's not a reason to downvote the question. It's a legit request and the answer below advised him how to address best he can, given the situation. Drupageddon-related hacks are difficult to spot because of the varied ways sites were hacked and nearly impossible to completely remedy this late after the fact.

Comment: Thanks Scotself ,I was able to fix the issue .. It was helpful Appreciate for standing by and helping ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an sftp.inc in the filetransfer folder in Drupal core by default. Perhaps more information on your contributed modules in use, a custom module, Drupal version, etc. might help...

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible that file might get deleted automatically , bcoz I have not made any changes , only thing I have done is, deleted all the spam comments and thereafter I am seeing this error

Comment: What version of Drupal are you running? Have you looked at the contents of sftp.inc?

Comment: Iam using 7.16, No I have not , you want me to check for the file sftp.inc right? whether it exist in folder or not

Comment: That would be a start, but my first inclination is that since you're 22 releases behind in Drupal core updates (now on 7.38) that you're really dealing with a symptom of "Drupalgeddon". https://www.drupal.org/PSA-2014-003 gives some info related and the [Drupalgeddon module](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgeddon) helps quite a bit in tracking down the places where you might have been hacked and provides a lot of info in rectifying those. HOWEVER! these steps are NO guarantee that your site is not permanently and irreversibly hacked. Lots of reading material out there on this. Good luck!